# PL/SQL Function for Correct Shipping Address

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a PL/SQL function that when given the customer number looks to see if the order was sent to the customer address. If the customer's address matches the order address then the function needs to return True.  This is what I came up with but I can't get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function CorrectAddress
(aCustNo IN Customer.CustNo%TYPE) RETURN VARCHAR IS
 aCustStreet Customer.CustStreet%TYPE;
 aCustCity   Customer.CustCity%TYPE;
 aCustState Customer.CustState%TYPE;
 aOrdStreet OrderTbl.OrdStreet%TYPE;
 aOrdCity   OrderTbl.OrdCity%TYPE;
 aOrdState OrderTbl.OrdState%TYPE;
 RightAdd VARCHAR;

 BEGIN
 SELECT Customer.CustStreet, Customer.CustCity, Customer.CustState OrderTbl.OrdStreet, OrderTbl.OrdCity, OrderTbl.OrdState
 INTO aCustStreet, aCustCity, aCustState, aOrdStreet, aOrdCity, aOrdState
 FROM Customer, OrdertTbl
 WHERE Customer.CustNo = OrderTbl.CustNo;

 IF aCustStreet = aOrdStreet AND aCustCity = aOrdCity AND aCustState = aOrdState THEN RightAdd := True;
 ELSE RightAdd := False;
 END IF;

 END;
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so, post the error-- there's no benefit to making us guess.  If I had to guess, I'd guess that you either want to return a `boolean` or you are missing the quotes around both `True` and `False` if you want to return a `varchar2`.  You're also missing the `return` statement but that would be a runtime error rather than what I'm assuming is the compilation error you're getting.  You're probably also missing the predicate in your `SELECT` statement on `aCustNo`.  And unless a customer can only have 1 order, you're missing a predicate on the order number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, why did you want to return 'varchar', is it your custom type? if you want to return true/false you have to come with 'boolean', also you need to check whether you have rows in the table, for that you need to put exception handler

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE Function CorrectAddress
  (aCustNo IN Customer.CustNo%TYPE) RETURN boolean IS
   aCustStreet Customer.CustStreet%TYPE;
   aCustCity   Customer.CustCity%TYPE;
   aCustState Customer.CustState%TYPE;
   aOrdStreet OrderTbl.OrdStreet%TYPE;
   aOrdCity   OrderTbl.OrdCity%TYPE;
   aOrdState OrderTbl.OrdState%TYPE;

  `BEGIN
    SELECT 
    Customer.CustStreet, 
    Customer.CustCity, 
    Customer.CustState,
    OrderTbl.OrdStreet, 
    OrderTbl.OrdCity, 
    OrderTbl.OrdState
    INTO 
    aCustStreet, 
    aCustCity, 
    aCustState, 
    aOrdStreet, 
    aOrdCity, 
    aOrdState
    FROM 
   Customer, 
   OrdertTbl
   WHERE Customer.CustNo = OrderTbl.CustNo;`

  `IF aCustStreet = aOrdStreet AND aCustCity = aOrdCity AND aCustState = aOrdState THEN   
    return true;
   ELSE 
    return false;
   END IF;`

   `Exception 
     when no_data_found then
          return false;`

  `END;`
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed it to do I am still new to PL/SQL so I am not very good at yet.

Answer (score 0):

why not do something in these lines, much cleaner to read and why use all these fields when they are not needed (haven't tested the plsql block, but for the general idea check below);

```
    declare
      V_COUNTER number := 0;
      V_RESULT boolean;
    begin
        select
          count('x')
        into 
          V_COUNTER
        from 
          Order o
          inner join Customer c on c.Street = o.Street and
                                   c.City = o.City and  
                                   c.State = o.State
        where
          o.Orderid = 100100;


      if V_COUNTER = 0 then
        V_RESULT := False;
      else
        V_RESULT := True;
      end if;   
    end;
```

Comment: The reason I am using these fields is because they relate to a database we are using and we must make the Function work with the database.